# Get the numeric value before the text 'years' in postgres

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am trying out a query,

```
select (the_date::varchar ~ '-?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]* years') as date_ 
from customer
```

but it is simply returning true or false. How may I extract the actual numeric value please?

Comment: Assuming `the_date` is a date or timestamp variant, would `select extract(year from the_date) as date_ from customer` not be more suited for this type of query?

Comment: Is it RedShift? Try `select REGEXP_SUBSTR(the_date::varchar, '([0-9]+) years', 1, 1, 'e')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `SUBSTRING()`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(the_date::varchar FROM '-?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]* years?') AS date_
FROM customer
```

See docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

Comment: SQL Error [500310] [XX000]: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Not implemented
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Not implemented
  code:      1001
  context:   'false' - Function substring(text,text) not implemented - use REGEXP_SUBSTR instead
  query:     86179080

Comment: @Lilz: you are **not** using Postgres then

Answer (score 0):

`~` only checks if there is a match or not. To extract the number, use `substring`:

```
SELECT substring(the_date FROM '(-?[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*) years') AS date_
FROM customer;
```